# /usr/bin/script doesn't echo any command

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to use `/usr/bin/script`

> script makes a typescript of everything on your terminal session.  The terminal data are stored in raw form to the log file and information about timing to another (optional) structured log file.

it works fine on my personal machine.

with our linux server, nothing happens (it lools like my commands are not sent to the underlying shell)

```
$ which script
/usr/bin/script

$ /usr/bin/script -V
script from util-linux 2.23.2

$ /usr/bin/script test.script
Script started, file is test.script

ls

echo azdadazd

# CTRL-D doesn't work
# CTRL-C here
^C/usr/bin/lua: /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/../tools/base64.lua:34: interrupted!
stack traceback:
    /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/../tools/base64.lua:28: in function 'bit'
    /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/../tools/base64.lua:34: in function 'lor'
    /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/../tools/base64.lua:58: in function 'encode64'
    /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/utils.lua:159: in function 'build_MT_envT'
    /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/../shells/BaseShell.lua:182: in function 'expandMT'
    /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/../shells/BaseShell.lua:163: in function 'expand'
    /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/lmod:553: in function 'main'
    /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/lmod:570: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

what could be the cause of this ?

Comment: I wanted to tag with `script` but it was changed to `scripting` ...

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong but "/usr/bin/script test.script " shouldn't be hanging. And it's a cluster - it could be improper job submission to the cluster  or the cluster downloading the run time to sometime next week.

Comment: @CinaedSimson thanks, well it's unrelated to the cluster I think. When I said cluster I wasn't meaning that it was related to a job submission. I'm just working on the login node. I'll fix the text.

Comment: What's the value of env var TERM in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK got it. When using `/usr/bin/script` a new instance of the SHELL is launched. My shell is quite slow on startup, many underlying scripts are run. If I wait more than two minutes, I get the prompt at the end.

```
$ script samples.script
Script started, file is samples.script

(base) [me@login-01 ~]$
```